# ggplot2 is merging two different legend labels in a combined one

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, legend, factors

I'm trying to produce a scatter plot with ggplot for a shiny web app, to show the relationship between two variables(age and platelets, both numeric). Moreover, I want to add two additional dimensions to show possible differences in the linear relationship, plotted with color and shape (diabetes and anemia, both factor variables with possible values 0 or 1).

```
#selected() is a reactive function that apply filters to the dataframe
ggplot(data = selected(), aes(x=age, y=platelets, shape=diabetes, color=anaemia)) + geom_point()
```

This chunk of code is returning the following legend:

```
diabetes
0
(0,1)
(1,0)
1
```

And I was expecting the following output instead:

```
diabetes
0
1

anaemia
0
1
```

I have been reading at ggplot documentation but I didnt find a way to solve this problem. I really appreciate possible help to solve the problem.

Edit:
Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/andrewmvd/heart-failure-clinical-data

selected() function body

```
selected <- reactive({
    heart %>% 
      select(c(input$variables, response))
      filter(age >= input$age[1], age <= input$age[2])
  })
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**, a working **code** example and the **packages** you used? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ggplot2*'s default behavior is to have separate guides for each variable like you want. See the example below with code that is equivalent to what you have written.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg, shape = factor(am), color = factor(vs)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Is the code you showed actually what you are running that produces a different legend? If so, please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your example and I got the same output so I started to search the problem elsewhere. Finally, the problem appears when I wrap ggplot object inside a plotly wrapper, so it is not a ggplot fault, but plotly one.